# How to disable foundation or bootstrap styling for a block of html code?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, html-email, zurb-foundation

I am using mailgun (although this question has nothing to do with mailgun) to parse the incoming email and mailgun will http post the parsed email to my server. 
When I received the post, I got the html code for the multi-part email. 
I want to display the html email to my user, I am using rails, so it's something like

```
<div>
  <%= raw(message.body_html) %>
</div>
```

However, it looks different than it does when I view the same email in yahoo or hotmail (I know different email client will display the html email differently, but mine looks drastically different).

Here is how it looks on my self-built client:
[image: html email display in my self-built client]

And this is how it looks in yahoo for the same email:
[image: html email display in yahoo]

I use Zurb Foundation as my styling framework. However, I think the email html comes with its own in-line styling, I look at the code it does look like it does, then it should look similar enough with other clients.

So what is the best practice to display html email assuming you get a block of html code and want to display it as is without letting other frameworks overwriting its style?

Further more, is it possible to disable Foundation (or twitter bootstrap for that matter) styling for a block of code, for example, something like

```
<div>
  <% disable_foundation_styling begin %>
    <%= raw(message.body_html) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Of course "disable_foundation_styling" is only my imagination.

Thanks in advance!

!!!!!!!!! Update 1/1/2013 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

As @Alex L. suggested, I tried  but it doesn't quiet work as expected. 
The iframe renders everything in the view as before (see picture below), and that's understandable, since the iframe content is just the view of another controller, which in the case rails will include all the application layout templates as well. However, the toolbar is not my biggest concern, it's what's inside the iframe just looks exactly as before.
[image]

I suspect iframe may not be the way to do it. I look at the code of both gmail and yahoo, and they don't use iframe. Instead they use very deep nested  to render the html email. The part of the html email have the same code for both yahoo and gmail, except that yahoo insert an id of its own for every single DOM element.

So now I suspect there is some foundation styling that affected how it looks.

I will update once I find out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge it's not possible to instruct a browser to selectively ignore your page's CSS within a subset of the DOM. You have to explicitly override the page's existing style.

However, if you have an `iframe` element, the contents of that frame will be rendered independently of any styles applied to the containing page. So you could create a separate controller and view just for rendering the contents of your message, and use that as the source for the `iframe`.

Comment: this sounds plausible, let me try it tonight and update the result, thanks a lot.

Comment: it turns out <ifram> doesn't do the trick, please see my update in the question for more detail. 
Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: You should be using a special layout for the controller and view that's being rendered inside the iframe, or the controller should do `render :layout => false`. Zurb, Bootstrap, etc., will still be enabled within the iframe if you use your normal application layout to render the inline page.

Comment: although i haven't got it the way i want it to look, but it's irrelevant to the question. I tried :layout => false and your answer is good. Thanks.

Comment: Although the <iframe> works, but I feel that it's not the optimum solution in my particular case. In the messages_controller, it passes the @messages to the views to produce the feed-like layout, and each message contain its html, using <iframe> causes it to hit the server for each message. So if I am displaying 10 messages in a page, loading this page will require 11 requests, and the last 10 requests is redundant since the first requests already contain the data needed, the 10 extra requests are just for the iframe to render.

Comment: I can see how that would become though to support after a point. The only other thing I can think of is to refactor your stylesheets so that, instead of importing Foundation at the top-level of your application, you use SASS to selectively import pieces of it into parts of your own stylesheets (see [nested @import](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested-import)). After poking around inside Gmail, it doesn't look like anything magical happens with included HTML from an email. They don't have styles which apply globally (like Foundation does).